# Different ways of declaring enum in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, enums, enumeration

Why are there so many different ways to declare enums in objective c? It's pretty confusing.

Is there any difference between the following or are they all the same?

```
enum WeekDays{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
};

typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
} WeekDays;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, WeekDays){
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
};

enum {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
};
typedef NSInteger WeekDays;
```

Comment: This question is not specific to Objective-C, but is C. Only `NS_ENUM` is a convenience macro specifically available in Obj-C. Maybe you should investigate the semantics of a `typedef` instead of focusing on the `enum` only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typedef NS\_ENUM vs typedef enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191638/typedef-ns-enum-vs-typedef-enum)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the link. I now understand the difference between NS_ENUM and enum, but i'm still unsure about the differences in enum declarations.

Comment: Did you click on the NSHipster link?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the following or are they all the same?

There are differences, some due to C - which underlies Objective-C - and one if you are thinking about importing your Objective-C code into Swift.

Your first example:

```
enum WeekDays { Monday, ..., Friday };
```

is an original C `enum`. This declares a *type* `enum WeekDays`, with an *underlying type* of `int`, and 5 *literal* values.

Now C is not a strongly typed language: the literal values here do not have type `enum WeekDays` but rather are of type `int`; and variables of type `enum WeekDays` can be assigned values other than `Monday` thru `Friday`, and be assigned to `int` variables without casts or conversions. The first literal value (`Monday` here) will have the `int` value `0`, and following ones will have a value one greater then the preceding literal (so here `Friday` has the value `4`). Examples:

```
enum WeekDays one;
int two;

one = Monday;
two = Tuesday; // assigning enum literal to int is OK
two *= 42;     // will produce an int value outside of Monday thru Friday
one = two;     // which can be assigned to an enum WeekDays
one = 34;      // int values can also be directly assigned
```

*All* the `enum` variations are weak in this way. However many compilers, including those used by Xcode since at least v8, will issue warnings (not errors) in some cases, e.g. if a `switch` expression is an `enum` type and the `case` labels either omit some of the declared literals or have values outside the declared values.

**Giving the literals explicit values**

Rather than relying on the default values specific values can be given to `enum` literals. For example to give `Monday` the value `1` through to `Friday` having the value `5`:

```
enum WeekDays { Monday = 1, ..., Friday };
```

Literals without explicit values are assigned one more than the preceding literal as usual. The values do not need to be contiguous either:

```
enum WeekDays { Monday = 1, Tuesday = 42, Wednesday = 3, Thursday, Friday };
```

**Using a `typedef`**

Many C type declarations are complex and hard to parse (they are the stuff ion quiz questions), the C `typedef` allows an *alias* for a particular type to be declared. A `typedef` is often used with an `enum` declaration to avoid having to use `enum` when using the type. For example:

```
typedef enum WeekDays { Monday, ..., Friday } WeekDays;
```

declares the alias `WeekDays` to mean `enum WeekDays`. For example:

```
WeekDays one;      // means exactly the same as the previous
                   // declaration for one
enum WeekDays one; // also valid and means the same thing
```

Seeing `WeekDays` twice in the above declaration might be confusing, or simply too much typing for some people, and it can be omitted:

```
typedef enum { Monday, ..., Friday } WeekDays;
```

This is slightly different than the previous declaration, `WeekDays` is now an alias for an *anonymous* `enum`. With such a type the first form of declaration is now invalid:

```
enum Weekdays one; // invalid, no such enum
WeekDays one;      // valid
```

**Changing the underlying type**

By default the underlying type of an `enum` is `int`. A different *integral* type can be specified, the type must be large enough to hold all the values the literals represent. The integral types are the integer, unsigned integer and character types. The underlying type is specified by adding `: <type>` after the `enum` tag, and the literals can be given specific values of the same type. For example:

```
typedef enum Vowels : char { Letter_A = 'a', ..., Letter_U = 'u' } Vowels;
```

as above an anonymous enum may be used:

```
typedef enum : char { Letter_A = 'a', ..., Letter_U = 'u' } Vowels;
```

**Using `NS_ENUM`**

`NS_ENUM` is an (Apple) Objective-C convenience macro which expands out to a `typedef` and an `enum` declaration. For example:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, WeekDays) { Monday, ..., Friday };
```

expands to:

```
typedef enum WeekDays : NSInteger WeekDays;
enum WeekDays : NSInteger  { Monday, ..., Friday };
```

which avoiding the forward declaration is equivalent to:

```
typedef enum WeekDays : NSInteger { Monday, ..., Friday } WeekDays;
```

Using Xcode v8, at least, there are no differences in compiler checks and warnings between using `NS_ENUM` and the above direct `typedef`.

**When `NS_ENUM` makes a difference**

If you are writing Objective-C which will be used by Swift then using `NS_ENUM` does make a difference: an enum declared using `NS_ENUM` will be imported as a Swift `enum`; whereas one declared directly will be imported as a Swift `struct` and a collection of global read-only computed properties, one per literal.

Why this difference exists is not explained in the current Apple documentation (*Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4.0.3)*, available through *iBooks*)

**Finally, back to your examples**

The above should enable you to figure out the differences:

1. Default C `enum`, underlying type is `int`, type is used as `enum WeekDays`
2. Aliased C `enum`, underlying type is `NSUinteger`, type is used as `WeekDays`
3. `NS_ENUM` generated `enum`, underlying type is `NSInteger`, type can be referred to as either `WeekDays` or `enum WeekDays`
4. This declares *two* distinct types and will probably produce warnings. The first is an anonymous `enum` without an alias so no variables can later be introduced with this type. The literals it introduces are of type `int`. The second is an alias for `NSInteger`. On 64-bit systems `NSInteger` is 64-bits, while `int` is 32-bits, so assignments between the literal type (`int`) and the "enum" type (`WeekDays`) may produce warnings. Further `switch` statements will not be checked as with the previous three versions, as they are simply based on `NSInteger`. This version looks like an incorrect attempt to emulate `NS_ENUM` and should not be used (it is invalid as such, just doesn't do what it suggests).

Hopefully all that illuminates more than it confuses!

Comment: Wow that was a very in depth and complete explanation. Thanks so much.